# How to increase the border width of the progressbar(ttk) tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I increase the border width of progress bar in Thinker using Python. Below you can see my code, I have used length = 1360 and bd = 5 parameters but I can't manage to get the thickness I desired from the progress bar.

```py
from tkinter import ttk 
from tkinter.ttk import * 
from tkinter import * 
import tkinter 
root = Tk() root.configure(background = "sky blue") 
root.wm_attributes("-fullscreen","true")

progress = Progressbar(root, orient = HORIZONTAL, length = 1360,
                        maximum=150, mode = "determinate",
                        style="TProgressbar", bd=5) 


def bar():
    import time progress["value"] = 60 root.update_idletasks() 
    time.sleep(1)
    progress["value"] = 150
    root.update_idletasks() 
    time.sleep(1) 
    root.destroy() 
    progress.pack(pady=4) 


class HoverButton(tkinter.Button):
    def init(self, master, **kw):
        tkinter.Button.init(self,master=master,**kw) 
        self.defaultBackground = self["background"] 
        self.bind("", self.on_enter) 
        self.bind("", self.on_leave) 
    def on_enter(self, e):
        self["background"] = self["activebackground"] 
    def on_leave(self, e):
        self["background"] = self.defaultBackground


classButton = HoverButton(root,text="Start",padx=6,pady=1,
                          bd=7,font=("Eras Demi ITC",14,"bold"),
                          width=14, activebackground="purple",command=bar)

classButton.pack(pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a description of what you are trying to do, and fix the formatting of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Canvas (with a window in it) and add progressbar to that. In this way you can control the width, you desired.

```
    canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(self, relief = Tkinter.FLAT, width = 1200, height = 5)
    progressbar = Progressbar(canvas, orient=Tkinter.HORIZONTAL,
                              length=1360, mode="determinate" )

    canvas.create_window(1, 1, anchor=Tkinter.NW, window=progressbar)
    canvas.grid()
```